# QueryOver<IInterface> fetches all implementations

Tags: nhibernate, interface, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

Nhibernate has a nice feature, which I have discovered coincidentally:

```
public interface IInterface {}

public class Impl1 : IInterface {}

public class Impl2 : IInterface {}

ISession session = sf.OpenSession();
session.QueryOver<IInterface>().List();
```

This will fetch me all `Impl1` ans `Impl2` objects (in case those classes are mapped). They need not be mapped as `SubClassMaps`, which leads me to the conclusion that NHibernate resolves the implementing classes all by itself.

Can anyone send me the link to documentation on this one? I know neither the name nor the technical background of this feature...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this is just the way NHibernate does [inheritance mapping](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#inheritance).

In addition to the usage you described, you also have the ability to i.e. define a child collection on an object, using the base type and put any object of inherited type to the collection. For instance, you could have another entity containing a collection of your `IInterface` objects:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public IList<IInterface> MyCollection { get; set; }
}
```

Now you could put any object implementing `IInterface` into `MyCollection`, and NHibernate will persist them (if mapping is correct):

```
Impl1 i1 = new Impl1();
Impl2 i2 = new Impl2();
MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();
entity.MyCollection.Add(i1);
entity.MyCollection.Add(i2);

session.Save(entity);
```

However, the actual database usage (generated SQL) depends on the inheritance mapping strategy that you have defined, so get familiar with them first. You can read more in [official documentation](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#inheritance).